# BizTalk 2009. WCF-SAP. Error receiving IDOC's from SAP R/3

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, sap-erp, sap-r3

I got the problem receiving IDOC's in BizTalk 2009 after our SAP team has upgraded SAP R/3 from 4.3 to 7.4 version (not sure in exact version numbers).

The error in BizTalk 2009 Event log is:

---

```
The adapter "WCF-SAP" raised an error message. Details 

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, Microsoft.Adapters.Internal.LayeredChannelBindingElement.LayeredInboundChannel`1[System.ServiceModel.Channels.IReplyChannel], cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close()
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.Close().
```

---

I tried to increase receive timeout

But the error is still here.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Current value of ReceiveTimeout parameter is 24.20:31:23.6470000

Answer (score 0):

The erorr that the channel is in a Faulted state is a top-error just stating that an error occurred.

It might be useful to setup [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) to see the underlying error.

Take a look at the above link to see how.